# How to compare the Two CCSprite in cocos2d V3.x with IOS

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm working with the cocos2d 3.x and Xcode 5.1.1.And i need to compare two CCSprite from one to another (like a candy crush).i move the sprite (by tochMoved function) i need to compare with the next column sprite if it matched means it to be blazed otherwise it move the old position Any one help me..

Comment: You could compare textures or something, but a better way would be to make your tiles their own class with a member variable that stores what type of tile or "candy" it represents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to make this logic is use tag value of sprite to indicate "candy" type. Compare sprite texture is really bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

On cocos2d v3.5 you can use ccsprite name to compare.

Comment: This should be added as comment once you have enough reputation.